# flex and bison conflicting types for ‘yylval’

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc, flex-lexer, symbol-table

While compiling lex program an error obtained :
 conflicting types for ‘yylval’
 extern YYSTYPE *yylval;

Any idea how to correct this one?
This the the lex code

```
%{
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include"y.tab.h"
  extern char *yylval;
%}

%%
 "int"|"float"|"char"|"double" { yylval=strdup(yytext); return TYP;}
 [a-z A-Z][a-z A-Z 0-9]* { yylval=strdup(yytext); return ID;}
 ";" return SEMI;
 "," return COMA;
 "{" return LB;
 "}" return RB;
 "\n" return NL;
 [\t]+;
 .;
 %%
```

Comment: This is covered quite well in the documentation for `bison`.  Changing the type of YYLVAL depends on which Bison version you have.  See for example http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Rpcalc-Declarations.html#Rpcalc-Declarations

Answer (score 2):

You define `yylval` twice -- once as a `YYSTYPE` in your .y file (which is exported to `y.tab.h`) and a second time as `char *` in your lex code.  Get rid of the `extern char *yylval;` and the multiple definitions will go away, though you'll also need to change your *uses* of `yylval` in the lex code to be compatible with whatever you've defined in your `.y` file.